# Issue with Moq Assert for Generic Type

Tags: c#, .net-core, moq

I am new to Moq.

How do I assert a generic  type?

The type error occurs on this line of the test
`Assert.True(ServiceResponse<string>.Equals(result));`
with error

> Cannot access non-static method 'Equal' in static context

Full code is below

**Controller**

```
private readonly IAuthRepository _authRepo;
public AuthController(IAuthRepository authRepo)
{
    _authRepo = authRepo;
}

[HttpPost("Register")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ServiceResponse<int>>> Register(AddUserDtos user)
{
    var response = await _authRepo.Register(user);
    if (!response.Success)
    {
        return BadRequest(response);
    }
    return Ok(response);
}
```

**ServiceResponse**

```
public class ServiceResponse<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }

    public bool Success { get; set; } = true;

    public string Message { get; set; } = null;
}
```

**Test**

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    public Mock<IAuthRepository> repositoryStub = new Mock<IAuthRepository>();

    [Fact] 
    public async Task UnitOfWork_StateUnderTest_ExpectedBehaviour()
    {
        // Arrange
        repositoryStub.Setup(repo =>
                repo.Register(It.IsAny<AddUserDtos>()))
            .ReturnsAsync((ServiceResponse<string>) null); 

        var controller = new AuthController(repositoryStub.Object);

        AddUserDtos newUser = new AddUserDtosModel()
            {Company = "Test", Email = "email", FirstName = "", LastName = "", Password = "344343", Phone = "test"};
        // Act
        var result = await controller.Register(newUser);

        // Assert
        Assert.True(ServiceResponse<string>.Equals(result));
    }
}
```

Comment: First try to create an instance of ServiceResponse of what you are expecting to receive, and then check against the result received.

         `ServiceResponse<int> response = new ServiceResponse<int>() { 
          // fill in the properties that you want to check
            };
           Assert.True(response.Equals(result));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's amend the **Arrange** phase.
Rather than casting a `null` to `ServiceResponse<int>`, let's create a new instance:

```
// Arrange
ServiceResponse<int> response = new ServiceResponse<int>();
repositoryStub
    .Setup(repo =>repo.Register(It.IsAny<AddUserDtos>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(response);
```

Then you have several options to make sure that the returned object has a specific type.

#### as operator and null checks

You can simply try to cast the returned value to a specific type then check whether or it was successful:

```
var okResult = result as OkObjectResult;
Assert.NotNull(okResult);

var resultValue = okResult.Value as ServiceResponse<int>; 
Assert.NotNull(resultValue);
```

#### [IsAssignableFrom](https://xunit.net/docs/comparisons)

Here all you need to do is call the `IsAssignableFrom<T>` with the proper `T`

```
var okResult = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<OkObjectResult>result;
_ = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<ServiceResponse<int>>(okResult.Value);
```

#### GetType and [GetGenericTypeDefinition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition)

If you need to check the container class and the generic type separately
then you can do that as well:

```
var okResult = ...;
var resultValue = okResult.Value;

Assert.NotNull(resultValue);
Assert.Equal(typeof(ServiceResponse<>), resultValue.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition());
Assert.IsType<int>(resultValue.Data);
```